Is there a way to use Math.max on a template literal?
I'm new to coding and trying to complete my school task. The task goes like this:


Ask the user for one integer between 1 and 10.
Generate a random integer between 1-10.
Print the greater of these two numbers (given by the user and generated) using the max function.


Now when I'm trying to do the third one, my math.max keeps returning me NaN. I cannot figure it out, so I thought I would ask here. I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, proper feedback would be appreciated, thanks. :)
This the code I've written so far:
let number = prompt("Write an integer between 1-10: ");

const randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
document.getElementById("random").innerHTML=(`The generated integer is ${randomnum}`);

let number1 = Math.max(`${number}, ${randomnum}`));
document.getElementById("mathmax").innerHTML=(`From these two integers, ${number1} is greater`);


It should be Math.max(number, randomnum), there's no need for a template string.

Math.max(${number}, ${randomnum})) -> Math.max(Number(number), randomnum). prompt return string. there is an implicit conversion of a string to a number, but it is better to do it explicitly, or even better before placing it in the function and make sure that the number is received, and not something else

You need to provide two separate arguments to the Math.max() method, not a single interpolated string. Also note that strings don't need to be within parentheses. Try this:


let number = prompt("Write an integer between 1-10: ");

const randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = `The generated integer is ${randomnum}`;

let number1 = Math.max(number, randomnum);
document.getElementById("mathmax").innerHTML = `From these two integers, ${number1} is greater`;
<p>Random: <span id="random"></span></p>
<p>Max: <span id="mathmax"></span></p>



